# OAuth - getting invalid JSON in response of exchange code

Tags: oauth2

In OAuth 2.0 flow, I am getting invalid JSON in the response when I exchange authorization code for access_token.

I am getting following JSON -

```
{
    "access_token": "<ACCESS_TOKEN>",
    "signature": "<SIGNATURE>",
    "scop
     e": "id",
    "instance_url": "https://ap2.salesforce.com",
    "id": "https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D28000000dagMEAQ/00528000000GpGIAA0",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "issued_at": "1455706399354"
}
```

Please notice an extra line break in scope field.

This happens only sometimes and on firefox.

Comment: Can you try an option without pretty print JSON ?

Comment: Given output is without pretty print. I have formatted it before posting the question

Comment: it should not happen. how you are sending your request? any client or code ?